# How to install Vagrant plugin using VPN and proxy?

Tags: vagrant

My host is a Windows 10 Pro. I installed vagrant on it some time ago. Now I use VPN and proxy and I wanted to install **vagrant-proxyconf** plugin. It is a result:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
Installing the 'vagrant-proxyconf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused
by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity issues, proxy
filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured
plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message
below to help resolve the issue:

  timed out (https://gems.hashicorp.com/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://gems.hashicorp.com/
```

Plugin is installed properly when I disable VPN and proxy. It seems that vagrant does not use system proxy and I have to set proxy somewhere in vagrant configuration but I do not how to do it. I googled this issue but I have found issues with proxy on guest machine.

My question concerns only host and plugin installation. I also have problem with guest but it is separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I set http_proxy environment variable and plugin is installed properly.

```
set http_proxy=http://yourproxyserver:port
```

I found solution [here](https://digitaldrummerj.me/vagrant-behind-proxy-server/)